# Using/updating BlendsCAD to 2.92

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to use [BlendsCAD](https://github.com/3DLIRIOUS/BlendSCAD), but I keep getting error messages:

- `AttributeError: 'Material' object has no attribute 'use_object_color`
- `AttributeError: 'Material' object has no attribute 'use_transparency'`
- `AttributeError: 'Material' object has no attribute 'transparency_method'`

I cannot find documentation for the attributes in the current API docs, but I do in 2.64.

Is this an API update issue? or something else and if so, any hints as to what to search for? and is there documentation on deprecated APIs?

Comment: I think these properties are for the older, deprecated Blender Internal render engine. Looks like the add-on hasn't been updated in 4 years. That means you'll have to use an older blender version (or manually update it, but that looks like a big undertaking)

Comment: Newer versions of blender use a Principled BSDF for the starting (base) material - it's likely these attributes have been renamed since 2.64. If I had to guess, "use_object_color" would refer to the _BaseColor_ --  (`bpy.data.materials["Material"].node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[0].default_value = (1, 1, 1, 1)`)  -- "use_transparency" would be _Alpha_ - (`bpy.data.materials["Material"].node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[19].default_value = 1.0`)  -- and "transparency_method" would be _Blend Mode_ - (`bpy.context.object.active_material.blend_method = 'BLEND'`)

Comment: @ChristopherBennett - thanks that's a good lead. Do you know of a document suimmarizing breaking changes? or alternatively of a good guide to debugging (better than launch - fail - shutdown - fix - relaunch, which is taking me ages)